# How to sort data from firebase with boolean value (true and false) in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I added some data to the collection. When I retrieve it, it has to be sorted by it's true and false value. What I meant is If the value is false then they must bee seen on top. If the value is true they should be seen at the bottom. Is it possible to make firebase to sort it in this order?

```
 stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('request')
            .where('created_at', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: today)
            .where('isAccepted', isEqualTo: false & true)
            .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
```

This only showing the data with false value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `isAccepted` is the parameter that is boolean, then the query should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('request')
    .orderBy('isAccepted', descending: false)
    .snapshots();
```

With ascending order, false values will be at the top, followed by true values.

Comment: hi @pszklarska thanks, i tried it and error occured --- The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<User>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<User>#00644):
The 'FieldPath([isAccepted])' cannot be the same as your where() field parameter 'FieldPath([isAccepted])'.

Answer (score 0):

This condition looks wrong in your code:

```
.where('isAccepted', isEqualTo: false & true)
```

If you want to return documents where `isAccepted` is either `true` or `false`, you do that with an `in` condition:

This condition looks wrong in your code:

```
.where('isAccepted', whereIn: [false, true])
```